# Unable to apply gradle script plugin from HTTP URL

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I use gradle v4.2 and here is my build.gradle. I need to apply script plugin which has a very simple custom task located in my github url.

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply from: 'https://github.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/blob/master/custom.gradle'
```

However I get the following output:

```
    Download https://github.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/blob/master/custom.gradle

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    Where:
    Script 
    'https://github.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/blob/master/custom.gradle' 
     line: 7

    What went wrong:
   Could not compile script 


  'https://github.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/blob/master/custom.gradle'.
  > startup failed:
  script 
 'https://github.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/blob/master/custom.gradle': 
  7: unexpected token: < @ line 7, column 1.
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 ^

 1 error
```

While the same custom.gradle works fine when I reference from my local directory:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply from: 'custom.gradle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you reference it as a web page not `raw`, however try it as raw

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/contactsai123/TestAssured/master/custom.gradle
```

It should work as expected